# Accepting conditional input for PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL in SQL Developer:

I am trying to package together a couple queries my team uses to lookup information to verify with. I have a query that returns a bunch of information on a given customer. The returned columns will always be the same (cust_id, name, zip_cd) but what changes is how the user searches for the customer. Sometimes we have a customer ID we can search on directly, sometimes it's just name and zip_cd.

Is there a way I can create a single query where it prompts the user how they want to search (ie by cust_id OR by name and zip_cd) and then prompts the user to enter the cust_id OR name and zip_cd depending on their previous input?

Also, ideally I would LOVE for this to be displayed in the results pane like a normal query, but the best solution I could come up with so far was to use a cursor. If you have any input on how I can do that it would be greatly appreciated!

This was something like my first query:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT choice_prompt PROMPT 'Enter seach criteria: (1) cust_id (2) name and zip_cd: ';
ACCEPT cust_id_prompt PROMPT 'Enter cust_id: '
ACCEPT cust_name_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer name: '
ACCEPT cust_zip_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer zip cd: '
BEGIN
    IF &choice_prompt = '1' THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE a.cust_id = &cust_id_prompt
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSIF &choice_prompt = '2' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE b.cust_zip = &cust_zip_prompt AND c.cust_nm = &cust_name_prompt
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('There were errors.');
    END IF;
END;
```

But it kept prompting me for everything instead of just what was needed. So then I tried embedding the ACCEPT PROMPT into the relevant choices like so, but couldn't get it to work:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT choice_prompt PROMPT 'Enter seach criteria: (1) cust_id (2) name and zip_cd: ';
BEGIN
    IF &choice_prompt = '1' THEN 
        ACCEPT cust_id_prompt PROMPT 'Enter cust_id: '
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE a.cust_id = &cust_id_prompt
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSIF &choice_prompt = '2' THEN
        ACCEPT cust_name_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer name: '
        ACCEPT cust_zip_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer zip cd: '
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE b.cust_zip = &cust_zip_prompt AND c.cust_nm = &cust_name_prompt
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('There were errors.');
    END IF;
END;
```

So then I tried just using input variables and that executed, but it still prompted for everything instead of just what was needed:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT choice_prompt PROMPT 'Enter seach criteria: (1) cust_id (2) name and zip_cd: ';
DECLARE
    enter_cust_id number;
    enter_cust_name varchar2(20);
    enter_cust_zip_cd varchar2(5)
BEGIN
    IF &choice_prompt = '1' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE a.cust_id = &enter_cust_id
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSIF &choice_prompt = '2' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('cust_id'||chr(9)||'cust_nm'||chr(9)||'cust_zip');
        FOR r_product IN (
            SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
            FROM customers.cust_id a 
            JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
            JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
            WHERE b.cust_zip = &enter_cust_zip_cd AND c.cust_nm = &enter_cust_name
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line( a.cust_id ||chr(9)|| c.cust_nm || chr(9) || b.cust_zip );
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('There were errors.');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be helpful.  that is a lot of code to look at

Comment: A couple of things: First, `ACCEPT ... PROMPT` is a sqlplus or sqlcl construct, not a SQL construct, so you can't embed those commands inside your SQL code block between the `BEGIN` and `END` statements. Typically these cases are handled through execution of separate scripts - one for each search type - as there really isn't a good way to code menus into these scripts.  Second, the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package isn't really intended to produce large volumes of output for users. It's purpose is more for informational or troubleshooting messages. The buffer it has to use is of limited size.

Comment: Third, looping through your output to display it one line at a time is going to be a performance killer. Is there a reason you're outputting your data as a script in SQL Developer instead of returning it as a result set to a worksheet? As soon as you start throwing around command-line instructions like `ACCEPT` and `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` you are limiting yourself to text output and you can't use the normal query worksheet output.

Comment: @pmdba, I have a large, complex query that, depending on how the user is searching for a customer, uses one of many subqueries. Currently the user uncomments the one they want to use and comments out the ones they don't want to use. My users have almost no experience with SQL so I am trying to make the process as user friendly as possible. I am familiar with SQL, but the PL part is new to me. Is there a way to do this in SQL or is my current method of commenting and uncommenting subqueries pretty much how it's supposed to be done? Would Python interfacing with SQL be more appropriate?

Comment: Are you able to create additional database objects, like views, types, or stored procedures?

Comment: @pmdba, right now I just have "read only" access as I just started the position recently. I am fairly confident that if I request it, it would be granted. However, I am getting the feeling it would just be better for everyone if I wrote it in Python. Which begs the question... What is the PL part of PLSQL useful for? Is it more of a DBA thing?

Comment: PL/SQL is generally *not* object oriented: it is often used to build APIs to support external applications. Think "back-end" code vs. "front-end". It keeps the SQL set processing *in* the database, where it is efficient, rather than push rows of data over the network for slow, row-by-row processing on an application server. Your business logic is coded into the API and the data structures in the database for universal enforcement; your front-end GUI interacts with the PL/SQL API to manipulate the data.

Comment: Having a PL/SQL-based API makes it relatively easy to rebuild the GUI front-end when the next hot thing after Python comes along. Remember C++, Perl, Ruby, Java, C#, JavaScript, and others? There's a new front-end paradigm literally every year or two.  PL/SQL has outlived *all* of them, by decades. When your back-end API is designed and used correctly you won't have to rebuild all of your business logic to migrate to a new front-end language - only the interactive user bits that make the API calls. This makes migration and redesign of a GUI *much* simpler and faster, by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply run the queries as is - with the substitution variables - in SQL Developer, it will prompt you automatically to fill them. There is no need to use scripting commands like `ACCEPT ... PROMPT` at all. As soon as you do that you are limited to text output from the script and have no ability to use the normal results worksheet or other result set tools.

```
SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
  FROM customers.cust_id a 
  JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
  JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
 WHERE a.cust_id = &enter_cust_id;

SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
  FROM customers.cust_id a 
  JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
  JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
 WHERE b.cust_zip = &enter_cust_zip_cd AND c.cust_nm = &enter_cust_name;
```

You can keep the queries in the same file, and just select and run the query you want specifically. You would get your results in the normal results pane as desired and not have to deal with text output (again, `DBMS_OUTPUT` *really* isn't intended for the purpose you have used it). Just be sure to use the "Run Statement" button (green arrow) to run a specific command (so no need to comment things out) and not the "Run Script (F5)" button.

Maybe this is what you are already doing, in which case there really isn't much more to be done within SQL Developer. As has been pointed out, PL/SQL isn't really the sort of language you can build a user interface with. It's more about building an API to support a UI coded in some other language. If you need a real user interface, look at Python or Oracle Application Express (APEX), a low/no-code solution which is included with your Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Generally PL/SQL is not great for things that need to be interactive with the user - something like Python will be much easier to work with.  However for this case, you may not need either..  could you do something like the following?

```
ACCEPT cust_id_prompt PROMPT 'Enter cust_id: '
ACCEPT cust_name_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer name: '
ACCEPT cust_zip_prompt PROMPT 'Enter customer zip cd: '

SELECT a.cust_id, c.cust_nm, b.cust_zip 
FROM customers.cust_id a 
JOIN customers.cust_addr b ON a.xref_id = b.xref_id 
JOIN customers.cust_nm c ON a.xref_id = c.xref_id  
WHERE (a.cust_id = &cust_id_prompt or '&cust_id_prompt' is null)
AND ((b.cust_zip = &enter_cust_zip_cd and c.cust_nm = &enter_cust_name) or '&enter_cust_zip_cd' is null)
AND ('&cust_id_prompt' is not null or '&enter_cust_zip_cd' is not null);
```

Basically, if I provide input use it to search.  The last line is just in there to ensure you don't enter blanks for everything and get back the whole table.

There would be other benefits that using Python, etc will provide (easier to have unit tests around your code, a better user interface, etc) - but if you are looking for a quick and dirty solution staying in SQL*PLUS, this may get you there.

Comment: thanks! I'll code it in Python. So, I thought the PL part of PLSQL was more for something like this. I heard a number of people say the PL part brought OOP functionality to SQL, but after all this it makes me wonder what its real purpose is. Is it more for the DBA side of things or does it have other uses? Like, I get the concept of it, but I can't think of any scenarios where I would use it over standard SQL.

Comment: @LF2142 Using these `PROMPT` commands is unnecessary: SQL Developer will prompt you automatically in the GUI for substitution variables using the normal "Run Command" execution. When you use "Run as Script" you are limited exclusively to text output.

Comment: @pmdba Great catch!.. I overlooked the SQL Developer part of his comments and was thinking SQL*plus